# [Content_Types].xml folder different make System.IO.Packaging.Package can't read Uri information

Tags: .net, zip

[Content_Types].xml folder different make System.IO.Packaging.Package can't read Uri information.

My [Content_Types].xml use extension search :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Types xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types">
    <Default Extension="xml" ContentType="" />
</Types>
```

But, I just add a folder before `style.xml` then `System.IO.Packaging.Package` can't get `Uri` information
[image]

My Code:

```
namespace ZipSample
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;
    using System.IO.Packaging;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Execute(xmlpath:@"styles.xml");
            Execute(xmlpath:@"test\styles.xml");
        }
        
        public static void Execute(string xmlpath)
        {
            var path = "output.zip";
            File.Delete(path);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false, UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    AddStringToZip(archive, xmlpath, @"");
                    AddStringToZip(archive,
                        @"[Content_Types].xml", @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Types xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"">
    <Default Extension=""xml"" ContentType="""" />
</Types>");
                }
            }

            using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(path))
            {
                var part = zip.GetParts().Select(s => new { s.CompressionOption, s.ContentType, s.Uri, s.Package.GetType().Name }).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine($"xmlpath:{xmlpath}  |  CompressionOption:{part?.CompressionOption} |  Uri:{part?.Uri}");
            }
        }

        private static void AddStringToZip(ZipArchive archive, string entryPath, string content)
        {
            var utf8WithBom = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true);
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryPath);
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, utf8WithBom))
                writer.Write(content);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the key point : it should use `/` not `\`

e.g:

```
namespace ZipSample
{
    using System;
    using System.IO;
    using System.IO.Compression;
    using System.IO.Packaging;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Execute(xmlpath:@"styles.xml");
            Execute(xmlpath:@"test/styles.xml");
        }
        
        public static void Execute(string xmlpath)
        {
            var path = "output.zip";
            File.Delete(path);
            using (var stream = new FileStream(path,FileMode.CreateNew,FileAccess.ReadWrite))
            {
                using (ZipArchive archive = new ZipArchive(stream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false, UTF8Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    AddStringToZip(archive, xmlpath, @"");
                    AddStringToZip(archive,
                        @"[Content_Types].xml", @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8""?>
<Types xmlns=""http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/content-types"">
    <Default Extension=""xml"" ContentType="""" />
</Types>");
                }
            }

            using (Package zip = System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(path))
            {
                var part = zip.GetParts().Select(s => new { s.CompressionOption, s.ContentType, s.Uri, s.Package.GetType().Name }).FirstOrDefault();
                Console.WriteLine($"xmlpath:{xmlpath}  |  CompressionOption:{part?.CompressionOption} |  Uri:{part?.Uri}");
            }
        }

        private static void AddStringToZip(ZipArchive archive, string entryPath, string content)
        {
            var utf8WithBom = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding(true);
            ZipArchiveEntry entry = archive.CreateEntry(entryPath);
            using (var stream = entry.Open())
            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream, utf8WithBom))
                writer.Write(content);
        }
    }
}
```